# Synchronous Android activities

Tags: android

Ive made mis-leading topic in my last question, so i open this new question to clear what I realy want. sorry for the inconvenience.

I wanna run two system(Android) activities one after another in specific order from my main activity.

now as we know, startActivity is an asynchronous operation, so i cant keep on a specific order.

so i thought maybe I should try to do it with dialogBox in the middle but also running a dialogBox is an asynchronous.

now as i said the activities which i try to run are Android activities, so i cant even start them with startActivityForResult (or mybe i can, but i dont get any result back to my main(calling) activity)
Any tricks how could i manage with this issue?

Some code:

first activity:

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(); 
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
      intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS); 
      startActivity(intent);
```

second activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(tmpPackageFile 
        .getAbsoluteFile()), 
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

as you can see, i dont have any access to those activites, i can just run thire intents from my main activity.

Comment: I guess you launch the settings activity because some settings is not set correctly for your activity? Why can't you just check if that settings is correct in onResume()?

Comment: What did you mean in onResume? why would i check it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't have 2 activities running at the same time, start the first, and then start the second once the first returns.

One way of tracking this is to use the startActivityForResult method, it should allow you to control the order the activities are created.

Comment: Ive tried that, it didnt work.. onActivityResult never being invoked in my calling activity.. (mybe coz result never sent back??) !!

Comment: Have you tried without FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK? Reading up on the documentation it seems like it might be the issue: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // start the other activity

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Handle cancel
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

{
    String msg="Android";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(msg,"1:application created");

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(msg,"2 The onStart() ");
    }
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(msg, "3 The onResume() ");
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(msg, "4 The onPause() ");
    }
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(msg, " 5 The onStop() ");
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(msg, "6 The onDestroy()");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use the preview to see if your code is being formatted right, and add some text, maybe a quote with a link where the user can find out more about your reply, and understand better the answer.